# How get results with 3 (various) days away (difference) from the current date?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, mysqli

Im developing a log system at the moment. My knowledge of PHP is good, mysqli I just know the basic things.

I want to send a email(cronjob) 3 days before the next event, the date is stored in the database. The email is stored in the users table, and the new_event column is in a different table.

My question is how do I get all the email adresses that are 3 days away from the current date?

I'm not asking for a premade query, I just need a push in the right direction, of how to handle this.

Comment: Do you have some way of knowing if an email address has had an email sent to it? Just finding addresses that are 3 days away from the current date is not enough.

Comment: thank you for your answer,but the event date is entered by users themselfs. So for every user its a different date. and about 4-6months is the next one. Also submitted by the user. I want to make a cronjob, with a query that looks for all emails with an event 3 days away every evening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this to add 3 days:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE date_send = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

You can read more at:

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. This is a push in the right dirrection, as the function does exactly what i want.